# Capturing frames from web cam, image is cropped

Tags: python, windows, opencv, flask

Everything I'm using is on Windows 10 Enterprise.

I remote desktop into this windows machine, it's got a Flask API, which has a route which captures the latest frame from the webcam with Open CV and writes the images to a folder.

If I disconnect from the machine (Without logging out), after 2 hours or so, the images that are captured and written are cropped to the top left of the screen. I can't replicate this when I'm connected remotely. What's strange is the cropped picture is the same resolution as the uncropped, full picture.

They look like this:

[Cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkVc1.png)

All images, cropped or not are 640 x 480.

Here's the route which writes the current image from the webcam to a folder.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
# Use Flask's caching feature to cache the CAP (So it doesn't set it everytime we call a route)
app.cache = cap

@app.route('/next')
def next():
    cv_cap = app.cache
    file_name = urllib.parse.unquote(request.args.get('fileName')).replace("{{}}", "{}")
    if not os.path.exists('C:/Users/Public/photos'):
        os.makedirs('C:/Users/Public/photos')
    if cv_cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cv_cap.read()
        if ret:
            # Paste frames inside the shared folder
            out_path = "C:/Users/Public/photos"
            frame = frame.reshape((480, 640, 3))
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_path, file_name), frame)
            # Check if we need to clear space
            photo_files = glob(os.path.join(out_path, f'*.jpg'))
            if len(photo_files) > 5000:
                delete_old_photos(photo_files)
            response = {
                'image_name': file_name
            }
            return jsonify(response), 200
        else:
            print("Image could not be read")
            return Response(status=500)
    else:
        print("COULD NOT OPEN CAP")
        return Response(status=500)
```

I manage to resolve it by opening up the Windows Camera app, this must reset a driver or something which fixes it.

Is there a setting in Windows that I need to select? It could be the USB driver going to sleep or something similar.

Comment: is there any screencapturing involved here? [mre] required. if you want help from OpenCV people, remove all the flask stuff. if you think it's a flask problem, remove all the OpenCV stuff.